# position:relative в сетке bootstrap

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

При создании кругового меню столкнулся с проблемой того что контейнер для меню со свойством `position: relative;` при уменьшении экрана выходит за границы области для него предназначенной (находится все это в системе сеток `bootstrap3`). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это предотвратить?

Ширина и высота заданы в `vmin` так как требуется соблюсти пропорции квадрата.

Comment: Т.е. существует три колонки, меню расположено по середине и при уменьшении экрана центральный блок с меню просто наезжает на правую колонку.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, добавить пример кода, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ситуацию? Или воссоздать ее на таких ресурсах как [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) или [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://codepen.io/Fess/pen/adOgRN?editors=110 вот пример кода, буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: За границы выходит не контейнер, а само меню `<nav class="circle-menu">`, т.к. у него фиксированная ширина. Колонка сетки Bootstrap соответственно уменьшается при ресайзе экрана, т.к. ширина у нее в процентах, но сама колонка никак не будет урезать дочерний элемент с фиксированной шириной. Если ширина дочернего элемента задана в абсолютных единицах (не auto), то она не будет зависеть от родителя.

Comment: Я так понимаю, в случае если меню начинает выходить за гранцы колонки Bootstrap, то меню должно начинать принимать ширину колонки? Обязательно ли использование `vmin` в вашем случае? Это привязка к размеру экрана или просто для сохранения формы квадрата?

Comment: vmin использую только для сохранения формы квадрата, да вы правы мне требуется привязать меню чтобы оно не выходило за рамки центральной колонки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для пропорционального изменения размера сторон элемента можно воспользоваться поведением CSS свойства `padding`. Если указывать его величину в процентном соотношении, то процент будет расщитывается от ширины `width` родительского элемента. Таким, образом в вашем случае в классе меню можно заменить строчки:

```
height: 80vmin;
width: 80vmin;
```

на

```
height: 0;
width: 75%;
padding-bottom: 75%;
```

Значение `75%` будет расчитываться от ширины родителя, т.е. от ширины колонки Bootstrap. Т.к. высота элемента будет основана только на `padding`, нужно установить `height` в `0`, чтобы высота не влияла на размеры.

[Здест обновленный код вашего пример на CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPPBKO)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста еще один момент, возможно ли разместить в сегменте круга адаптивное  изображение?

Comment: @ИванСмирнов, я бы посоветовал создать еще один вопрос и уже там описать возникшую проблему, если она не относится к проблеме текущего